# Is there a limit to the number of events being returned?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Questions:
Is there a limit to the number of events returned in total before Fullcalendar breaks? Could my issue possibly be a memory limit?

Background:
We've been running Fullcalendar for about 2 or 3 months now with no issues. My query is very simple and pulls all active events that don't have a deleted flag set. (SELECT * FROM event_cal WHERE deleted = '0')

Sometime today, the calendar stopped showing events. It was just a blank calendar. After trying to figure out what the issue was In started messing with the query. I only have 96 records in the table in total. If I return results WHERE event_id >= 30 (records 0 - 30) it works as it should. If I return results WHERE event_id <= 30 (records 30 - 96) it works as it should.

So why when I run it wide open and return all results (96) does it not display any events in the calendar?

Comment: There's no hard limit, but yes obviously memory will be a limit, and also realistically there's a soft limit in terms of the number of events it's realistic to display at once, and what would be legible and understandable by a human being reading the calendar. But 96 isn't a lot, in either of those terms.

Comment: `why when I run it wide open and return all results (96) does it not display any events in the calendar`...we can't possibly know, you didn't provide a [mre] of the issue, there isn't enough code, and there's no debugging info either - we are not logged into your server, we cannot see your memory usage stats, the error messages or output generated by the code, or look at your log files etc.

Comment: P.S. `My query is very simple and pulls all active events that don't have a deleted flag set`...an aside, that'll be fine in the short term but think about when your calendar has been operational for a while...then you _will_ potentially start to pull back thousands of historical events which could cause performance/memory issues, and which probably aren't going to be interesting for the user if they're a long time in the past.

Comment: Unless your system otherwise marks them as not active when they've aged a certain amount, you're going to want to restrict what you return to a list which is just those which intersect with the date range fullCalendar is currently displaying. Then if/when the user changes the date range in the display, it can automatically fetch more events for that date range (but if they don't, it won't).

Comment: If you're using a dynamic event source (which you really should be) as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function then fullcalendar provides you with the relevant start and end dates, for you to use in your backend query.